# AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only // regexp group(1) / big file xml

Tags: python, xml

I need to select data from a big sitemap XML file to get something like this :

```
(title,img,link,txt)
(title,img,link,txt)
(title,img,link,txt)
```

but when testing my code, I got this error :

```
# Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./u2.py", line 91, in <module>
  s.pluj(x,i)   File "./u2.py", line 46, in pluj
  tab.append = (xx.group(1)) AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only
```

Here is my code :

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

    import linecache
    import re


    def w2(arg1):
        wiersz = linecache.getline('a.xml', arg1)
        return  wiersz

    count = len(open('a.xml', 'rU').readlines())
    #print count

    class rep:

    #   tab = []
        def pluj(self, linia, nr):
            adres1 = r'\<loc\>\<\!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]\>\<\/loc\>'
            foto1  = r'\<image\:loc\>\<\!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]\>\<\/image\:loc\>'
            opis1  = r'\<image\:caption\>\<\!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]\>\<\/image\:caption\>'
            title1 = r'\<\image\:title\>\<\!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]\>\<\/image\:title\>'


            self.linia = linia
            #print linia
            tab = []
            adres = re.compile(adres1)
            foto = re.compile(foto1)
            opis = re.compile(opis1)
            title = re.compile(title1)               

            print nr
            if re.match(adres, linia):
                xx = adres.search(linia)

                tab.append = (xx.group(1))
            #   return xx.group(1)
            if re.match(foto, linia):
                xx = foto.search(linia)
                tab.append =  (xx.group(1))
#   return xx.group(1)
            if re.match(opis, linia):
                xx = opis.search(linia)
                tab.append =  (xx.group(1))
#   return xx.group(1)
            if re.match(title, linia):
                xx = title.search(linia)
                tab.append = (xx.group(1))
#   return xx.group(1)
            else: print "nope"

    ##################
    # end rep
    #################

    s = rep()

    i = 0
    while i <= count:

        x = w2(i) 
        #print s.pluj(x,i)                                                                                                   
        s.pluj(x,i)
        i += 1

    print s.tab
```

Comment: `tab.append = (xx.group(1))` not correct change it to `tab.append(xx.group(1))`

Comment: thx it works   good

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to change python list append by assigning. you have to use append.

```
In [24]: l = []

In [25]: l.append = 5  # wrong
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-cc4bc6747222> in <module>()
----> 1 l.append = 5

AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only

In [26]: l.append(5)   # correct way

In [27]: l
Out[27]: [5]
```